# Test for wrong Wifi password?

Tags: arduino-ide, wifi, esp32

Maybe this is a dumb question, but is there a way to test for wrong Wifi password?

I know you can do WL_CONNECT to check if the password works, but is there a command for checking if the password is wrong? Not just by waiting.

Comment: my esp is trying to connect to the WiFi

Comment: i guess that makes my esp client

Comment: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/40f456aca3a568a09a5bec275b36a79869ce8bef/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/ESP8266WiFiSTA.cpp#L633

Comment: there's no way to tell if a password is right or wrong other than by trying to use it.

Comment: @dandavis but the `WiFi` class does not return the info even though it's available. It simply returns an error.

Comment: @Juraj I think this comment is worth to be posted as an answer as it might be really useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information is available on SDK level. If you include `#include "user_interface.h"`, you can use function `wifi_station_get_connect_status()`. It returns one of:

```
STATION_GOT_IP
STATION_NO_AP_FOUND
STATION_CONNECT_FAIL
STATION_WRONG_PASSWORD
STATION_IDLE
```

The `WiFi.status()` function uses function `wifi_station_get_connect_status()`,  but returns WL_CONNECT_FAILED for STATION_WRONG_PASSWORD.

Answer (score 0):

one can check for wrong password using the following code snippet

```cpp
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.println("Connected successfully");
  }
  else if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL) 
  {
    Serial.println("Wifi network is not avaliable");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Password is not correct");
  }
```

more information can be found on GitHub here:
https://github.com/aeonSolutions/aeonlabs-ESP32-C-Base-Firmware-Libraries